# SQL different 'group by' and 'date range' subqueries slowing down entire query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pulling all the subqueries from the same table `a`, but require the information from columns `b.7dayclicks`, `c.7dayclicks` and `d.14dayclicks`.

The query goes something like this:

```
select
  a.higher_tier_id,
  a.lower_tier_id,
  b.7dayclicks,
  c.7dayclicks,
  d.14dayclicks
from
  a,
  (select higher_tier_id, 7dayclicks
   from a
   where day >= curdate() - 7
   group by higher_tier_id) b,
  (select lower_tier_id, 7dayclicks
   from a where day >= curdate() - 7
   group by lower_tier_id) c,
  (select lower_tier_id, 14dayclicks
   from a where day >= curdate() - 14
   group by lower_tier_id) d
where
  day >= curdate() - 3 
  and a.higher_tier_id = b.higher_tier_id
  and a.lower_tier_id = c.lower_tier_id
  and a.lower_tier_id = d.lower_tier_id
```

It's taking a really long time to run as a result. I'm trying to make it more efficient. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- 1st column gives the higher_id
- 2nd column gives the lower_id
- 3rd column gives the 7 day clicks sorted by higher_id level
- 4th column gives the 7 day clicks sorted by lower_id level
- 5th column gives the 14 day clicks sorted by lower_id level

I do think that there is definitely a way to put everything together without any joins, but I just can't find out how..

Comment: I think that you may turn some of this logic to the application to make more simple sql query.

Comment: Its hard to understand what your doing here you have some weird joins going on. Without knowing more I would say 1) Set curdate to a variable instead of calling within each of those queries. 2) make sure you have indexs properly set up on all of your columns for table a.

Comment: Hi Colin, what would you mean by setting curdate to a variable, and also indexes properly set up?

Comment: Please explain the design of your table... it seems like this query can be done without any joins at all, but I really don't get what each column is supposed to be doing (honestly, it seems a little less than optimally designed as is)

Comment: @GlennLow Did the index suggestion below help you?  How about a checkmark?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?  You get the higher and lower tier id's, then a sum of the 7 day clicks and the 14 day clicks.

```
select
  a.higher_tier_id,
  a.lower_tier_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN day >= curdate() - 7 THEN 7dayclicks ELSE 0 END),
  SUM(CASE WHEN day >= curdate() - 14 THEN 14dayclicks ELSE 0 END)
FROM a
GROUP BY a.higher_tier_id, a.lower_tier_id
```